# How can i get the item in a list when i click on it

Tags: python, wxpython, listctrl

when i doubleclick one line , return the item of the second column in this line.
how to achieve this? 
i found a function : GetItem().GetText()
but i don't know how to use it .
please give me an example.
or you can use some other methods.
thank you!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3156923/wxwidgets-how-to-catch-left-click-on-wxlistctrl does this answer your question? Instead of EVT_LEFT_UP you want EVT_LEFT_DCLICK(or possibly EVT_LIST_ITEM_SELECTED if single click is OK)

Comment: thank you all the same, acattle

Comment: Ah, it turns out I slightly misread your problem anyway. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation talks about how GetItem works, but I found a couple forum threads that explains it for you:

- http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1458398
- http://www.velocityreviews.com/forums/t351572-newbie-wxpython-listctrl-question.html